# Random card/Image using buttonjavascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I want to create a card game using java script. Being a beginner at java script, I am finding great difficulty finding a suitable tutorial for what I am trying to do. When the 'start game' button is selected, I want the computer to produce a random card. I have tried many ways of doing this and have came to no avail. Here is my code.

```
<html>

<head>      

<title>   Christmas Assignment  </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xmasass_1.css">


                <script type = "text/javascript">

            function randomImg(){   
    var myimages= [];

    myimages[1] = "cards/1.gif";
    myimages[2] = "cards/2.gif";
    myimages[3] = "cards/3.gif";
    myimages[4] = "cards/4.gif";
    myimages[5] = "cards/5.gif";
    myimages[6] = "cards/6.gif";
    myimages[7] = "cards/7.gif";
    myimages[8] = "cards/8.gif";
    myimages[9] = "cards/9.gif";
    myimages[10] = "cards/10.gif";
    myimages[11] = "cards/11.gif";
    myimages[12] = "cards/12.gif";
    myimages[13] = "cards/13.gif";

    function oddTrivia(){

        var randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random()*(oddtrivia.length));
        document.getElementById('comp').InnerHTML=myimages[randomImg]; 
    }


    ar total = 0;
    function randomImg(){

         var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*13)+1;
        document.getElementById('img1').src = 'die'+x+'.gif';
        document.getElementById('img2').src = 'die'+y+'.gif';
        document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = total;

     }

    var card1Image;
    var card2Image;
    var card3Image;
    var card4Image;
    var card5Image;
    var card6Image;

    function start(){
        var button = document.getElementById("startButton");
        button.addEventListener("click", pickCards, false);
        card1Image = document.getElementById("1");
        card2Image = document.getElementById("2");
        card3Image = document.getElementById("3");
        card4Image = document.getElementById("4");
        card5Image = document.getElementById("5");
        card6Image = document.getElementById("6");
    }
    function pickCards(){
        setImage(card1Image);
        setImage(card2Image);
        setImage(card3Image);
        setImage(card4Image);
        setImage(card5Image);
        setImage(card6Image);
    }
    function setImage(cardImg){
        var cardValue = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 13);
        cardImg.setAttribute("src", "C:Xmas Assignment/cards/" + cardValue + ".gif");
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
                </script>


    </head>


<body>





<div id = "settings">

<img src = "settings_img.png" width = "60" height = "60">


</div>



<div id = "bodydiv">


<h1> Card Game</h1>

<div id = "computer">

<img src = " cards/back.gif">


</div>

<div id = "comp" > Computer </div>


<div id ="arrow">

<img src ="arrow2.png" width = "100" height="100">

</div>

<div id = "player">

<img src = " cards/back.gif">

</div>

<div id = "play"> Player </div>

<div id = "kittens">

<button id = "startButton" onclick ="randomImg" >   Start Game  </button>


<div id = "buttons_1">
<button id ="higher"> Higher

</button>

<button id = "equal">   Equal 

</button>


<button id = "lower"> Lower
</button>
</div>



<button id = "draw"> Draw your Card
</button>



<div id = "resetscore"> <a href = "url">Reset Score </a>
</div>
</div>

<div id = "score">
</div>


</div>




</body>



</html>


body {
    background:#66ccff;


}

h1 {


    text-align:center;




}

#settings   {


    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;


}


#bodydiv    {

    width: 800px;
    height:600px;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    background:#ffccff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


#computer   {


            border-radius: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            left:35%;
            top:27%;

}


#player {

            border-radius: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            left:55%;
            top:27%;


}

#start_game {

    width :120px;
    height: 55px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    margin-top:50px;
    background:white;
    border:1px solid black;

}

#buttons_1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:20px;
}


#higher {

        width:140px;
        height:50px;
        font-size: 15px;
        border-radius:10px;
        font-weight:bold;
}


#equal {
        width:140px;
        height:50px;
        font-size: 15px;
        border-radius:10px;
        font-weight:bold;

}


#lower {
        width:140px;
        height:50px;
        font-size: 15px;
        border-radius:10px;
        font-weight:bold;

}


#draw {
    width:160px;
    height:30px;
    margin-left:325px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:#FFFFCC;
}


#resetscore {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}


#arrow {

    margin-left:370px;
    margin-top:-130px;
}

#comp {
    margin-top:240px;
    margin-left:265px;
}

#play{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:540px;
}
```

Comment: Try to debug your code first. I found many mistakes. Use your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

You code is kind of hard to read.

1. You forgot to close the "{" of your main function.
2. You are declaring "randomImg" again in the body of the "randomImg" function(use a different name).
3. You wrote 
   `ar total = 0;`
   I think you meant to write:
   `var total = 0;`
4. `oddtrivia` in the function "OddTrivia" is not defined.
5. `y` in the inner randomImg function is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Having poked a little bit at the code, here is a few things:

#### Problem no 1: `randomImg()`

It's hard to know your intentions, but you should likely begin with removing the start of your first function `randomImg(){`.

Because 1) It does not have an end and 2) If it actually spans everything then this line `window.addEventListener("load", start, false);`  will not load on startup (since it does not get executed until randomImg() gets executed, and by then the page has already loaded.)

#### Problem no 2: `Cannot set property 'src' of null"`

Now when the first problem is out of the way, you should see `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null"` if you look in your console. Yes, USE YOUR CONSOLE. Click on the error to show what causes it.  Here it is:

```
cardImg.setAttribute("src", "C:Xmas Assignment/cards/" + cardValue + ".gif");
```

This means that `cardImg` is `null`. We backtrack the first call of `setImage()` and find that the variable `card1Image` is passed in. So that must mean that `card1Image` also is `null`. You can check it yourself by adding a `console.log('card1Image', card1Image);` in your code. Or you add a breakpoint at that point. (Use the sources-tab in chrome dev tools, click at the line-numbering to add a break point. Refresh the page and it will stop at the break point. Now you can mouse-over variables to see their values.)

Let's look at where 'card1Image' is set.

```
card1Image = document.getElementById("1");
```

So why is this returning null? Do we even have a `id="1"` element in the html? That could be the reason. (It is.)

There are more problems, but I'll stop there, but when you have fixed this part AND have no errors please ask again. Always check your errors and if you ask a question here you should provide errors. And when you can also be more specific with your questions.

#### What might someone else have done differently?

When it comes to playing cards, why not an array of objects?

```
var cards = [ 
    { src : 'cards/1.gif', value: 1 },
    { src : 'cards/2.gif', value: 2 },
    { src : 'cards/3.gif', value: 3 },
    { src : 'cards/4.gif', value: 4 }
]; // (You can of course use code to generate it.)

// Then a function to put cards in the player's hand.
var playerHand = _.sample(cards, 2);
console.log(playerHand);
```

Here I assume [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#sample), a lightweight library for when you don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Considering this looks like a homework question, the OP probably isn't allowed to use `lodash`.